# Refer to/select a drive based only on its label? (i.e., not the drive letter)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to refer to a drive whose letter may change. I'd like to refer to it by its label (e.g., MyLabel (v:) within a Batch File.  It can be referred to by V:\ . I'd like to refer to it by MyLabel.

(This was posted on Experts Echange for a month with no answer. Let's see how fast SO answers it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bat file will give you the drive letter from a drive label:

```
Option Explicit
Dim num, args, objWMIService, objItem, colItems

set args = WScript.Arguments
num = args.Count

if num <> 1 then
   WScript.Echo "Usage: CScript DriveFromLabel.vbs <label>"
   WScript.Quit 1
end if

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")

For Each objItem in colItems
  If strcomp(objItem.VolumeName, args.Item(0), 1) = 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo objItem.Name
  End If
Next

WScript.Quit 0
```

Run it as:

```
 cscript /nologo DriveFromLabel.vbs label
```

Comment: Can you call .vbs scripts from .bat files?

Answer (score 7):

The previous answers seem either overly complicated, and/or not particularly suited to a batch file.

This simple one liner should place the desired drive letter in variable myDrive. Obviously change "My Label" to your actual label.

```
for /f %%D in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "My Label"') do set myDrive=%%D
```

If run from the command line (not in a batch file), then %%D must be changed to %D in both places.

Once the variable is set, you can refer to the drive using `%myDrive%`. For example

```
dir %myDrive%\someFolder
```

Comment: On another note, it seems this method requires administrator access. `Failed to register mof file(s). Only the administrator group members can use WMIC.EXE. Reason:Win32 Error: Access is denied.` I guess I'll have to come up with a solution using `vol` instead.

Comment: @Ajedi32 - Are you still on XP? WMIC works without admin privs since Vista.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Hopefully my company's IT department will finally get around to upgrading one of these days.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WMI query language for that.
Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592(VS.85).aspx for examples.
The information you are looking for is available e.g. through the property VolumeName of the Win32_LogicalDisk class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(VS.85).aspx

`SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE VolumeName="MyLabel"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple batch script getdrive.cmd to find a drive letter from a volume label. Just call "getdrive MyLabel" or getdrive "My Label".

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Initial variables
set TMPFILE=%~dp0getdrive.tmp
set driveletters=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
set MatchLabel_res=

for /L %%g in (2,1,25) do call :MatchLabel %%g %*

if not "%MatchLabel_res%"=="" echo %MatchLabel_res%

goto :END


:: Function to match a label with a drive letter. 
::
:: The first parameter is an integer from 1..26 that needs to be 
:: converted in a letter. It is easier looping on a number
:: than looping on letters.
::
:: The second parameter is the volume name passed-on to the script
:MatchLabel

:: result already found, just do nothing 
:: (necessary because there is no break for for loops)
if not "%MatchLabel_res%"=="" goto :eof

:: get the proper drive letter
call set dl=%%driveletters:~%1,1%%

:: strip-off the " in the volume name to be able to add them again further
set volname=%2
set volname=%volname:"=%

:: get the volume information on that disk
vol %dl%: > "%TMPFILE%" 2>&1

:: Drive/Volume does not exist, just quit
if not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :eof

set found=0
for /F "usebackq tokens=3 delims=:" %%g in (`find /C /I "%volname%" "%TMPFILE%"`) do set found=%%g

:: trick to stip any whitespaces
set /A found=%found% + 0


if not "%found%"=="0" set MatchLabel_res=%dl%:
goto :eof








:END

if exist "%TMPFILE%" del "%TMPFILE%"
endlocal
```