# Loop through drive letters and move file to USB

Tags: loops, batch-file, windows-xp-embedded

I have a back up batch file that will backup my files and create a zip file out of them, then move this zip file to a USB drive that will be plugged into the PC, the USB drive could be allocated a drive letter between E to H, dependant on what else is using the ports, the below code works on a Windows 7 PC but not on a Windows XP machine, which the Batch File is going to be used on

The USB drive letter changes depending on which machine I'm backing up and /or how many devices are connected and using drive letters, I don't want to get a choice, just move the file to whatever drive is plugged in as there will only ever be one drive plugged in at a time as it is only used for back up purposes

How can I make this work on an XP machine, it will only be used on an XP machine, also can I throw up and error if a USB drive is not found and delete the zip file, as this is all running from a CF card, embedded system, so space is limited to save any files

```
REM ------ Creation of a date stamp for the ZIP file on the USB and set the File Name Structure------


set DT=%DATE:/=-%
set timestamp=%DT:~7,3%%DT:~4,3%%DT:~10,4%
Set FileStamp=%BackupName%-%timeStamp%


REM ------ Creation of the ZIP file ------

%SupervisorPath%\7-ZipPortable\App\7-Zip\7z a -tzip %BackupPath%\Backup\%FileStamp%.zip %BackupPath%\Backup\

REM ------ Move the backup file to a USB drive with File Name and Date Stamp ------

for %%D in (E F G H) do if exist %%D: (
  echo Moving files to USB drive %%D:
  move /y "%BackupPath%\Backup\%FileStamp%.zip" %%D: >nul && (
    echo Files moved to USB drive successfully
    goto :break
  )
)
:break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put on your USB drive in root a file for example with name `BackupDrive.txt`. The content does not matter, but I suggest to store in the file something like

```
File to identify the USB backup drive. Never delete this file.
```

Set the hidden file attribute on this file.

In your batch file use:

```
for %%D in (E F G H) do if exist %%D:\BackupDrive.txt (
  echo Moving files to USB drive %%D:
  move /y "%BackupPath%\Backup\%FileStamp%.zip" %%D: >nul && (
    echo Files moved to USB drive successfully
    goto :break
  )
)
```

Or most likely better, you give your USB drive a unique label and find the drive by label, see

- [How to reference a volume/drive by label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065280/)
- [How to refer to/select a drive based only on its label (i.e. not the drive letter)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849/)

Comment: Unfortunately none of these are an options, as I don't know who will be doing a backup or what drive they will be using, so it looks like I will have to use the Copy to all of the locations and delete the file after copy