# How to return output of vbs script to R console?

Tags: windows, r, cygwin

I found a useful script at  [Refer to/select a drive based only on its label? (i.e., not the drive letter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849/refer-to-select-a-drive-based-only-on-its-label-i-e-not-the-drive-letter) and can run it either in a `cmd.exe` window or under cygwin to find drive letters on my computer.

What I can't figure out is how to get the returned string (e.g. `E:`) to show up in my R console.   If I run `system('cscript /nologo DriveFromLabel.vbs label',intern=TRUE)` I get `character(0)` as the result.

Is there some switch to make the result of this comment in a `cmd.exe` call visible to R,  or is there some way to create a script that calls `cygwin` and returns the `cscript` result to R?

Comment: Does it print something, but it does not end up in the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
 system('Cscript  /nologo your_path/DriveFromLabel.vbs DRIVE_LABEL',intern=TRUE)[1]
```

Comment: Well dang!  On my Windows7 system, it's `...[1]`,  but that solves the problem.  It must be some sort of "return(invisible())" thing going on.  It's always something simple :-).

Answer (score 2):

It could be that `cscript` writes to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. A small example using the following Bash script (`test.sh`):

```
echo spam 1>&2
```

also yields no captured result:

```
> spam = system("./test.sh", intern = TRUE)
spam
> spam
character(0)
```

The solution under Linux is now to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
> spam = system("./test.sh 2>&1", intern = TRUE)
> spam
[1] "spam"
```

You can have a look at [this link](http://programing-fun.blogspot.nl/2008/04/redirecting-standard-error-output-in.html) for redirecting `stderr` under Windows. Credits also to the answer of Brian Ripley to [this R-help post](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/06/08/32382.html). The documentation of `system` confirms my story:

> ```
> For command-line R, error messages written to ‘stderr’ will be
> sent to the terminal unless ‘ignore.stderr = TRUE’.  They can be
> captured (in the most likely shells) by
>
>    system("some command 2>&1", intern=TRUE)
> ```

under the `Stdout and stderr:` header.

Comment: the R documentation for `system` says both stderr and stdout are collected, though.

Comment: But my little example shows the contrary. Only stdout is captured by `system`. Maybe it means that both `stderr` and `stdout` are shown, but only `stdout` is captured when `intern = TRUE`.

Comment: this is very useful in general, even though for my simple call the checked answer is easiest.  I'll save your notes for future use in more complicated system calls.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a way:
`system("C:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe ./doletter.sh",intern=TRUE)`  , where `doletter` contains 
`cscript /nologo DriveFromLabel.vbs label'` successfully returns the drive letter.
Now I just have to do some tricks to load the desired "label" string into the shell script, which can "easily" be done by creating the `doletter.sh` file from scratch via an R function.