# Get the drive letter of a given volume?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

Given a hard drive volume name how can I get the drive letter using a batch file in Windows 7?

Comment: You might want to look at some of these solutions to see if they work for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849/refer-to-select-a-drive-based-only-on-its-label-i-e-not-the-drive-letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_logicaldisk | where {$_.volumename -eq "<volumename>"} | select DeviceID
```

Comment: Thank you David,  being just smart enough to be dangerous could you help me just a bit more?   This is the volume name of my external HDD where I backup my personal files.  "Backup_and_eMail" When I backup my wife's and daughter laptop they are assigned different driver letters.  I would like to avoid having to edit my batch file when I backup their computers by being able to use the HDD volume name somehow.    Regards, P.

Comment: Thank you David and everyone else who advised.   It seems that this is just what I was looking for, it does just what I need. for /f %%D in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "volumeName"') do set myDrive=%%D   Thanks and Regards, P.

Comment: @user3901114 Glad it worked for you.  Please mark my solution as answered when you have a chance.  As for your other question, I don't quite understand what you're trying to do.  Suggest you post a new question.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "volname=System Reserved"
FOR %%d IN (Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A) DO IF EXIST %%d:\. (
 FOR /f "tokens=5*" %%L IN ('VOL %%d:^|FIND /i "drive"'
  ) DO IF "%%L"=="is" IF "%%M"=="%volname%" ECHO %%d is %%M
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Demonstrating how to find driveletters with volumename `System Reserved`.